# I've found a really fun free online math game about measuring out lengths and such in the olden days. How do I share it?

Tags: discussion

As the title says, I have found this really cool little free game online that I really love and I think most people interested in mathematics will enjoy. It is called Euclid the game, here is the link. www.euclidthegame.org

You start out with stuff like finding the midpoint of a line using circles and quickly continue to harder stuff like constructing parallelograms.

My question is, where do I post this? It is free and has nothing to do with me but I think everyone would really enjoy it. I gave the discussion tag because I don't know what tag would fit. Again, maybe this is considered inappropriate in which case I will delete my post. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe at a forum, not a Q&A site like this one? Or you can make a question about good mathematical online games and post it as an answer. I'm not quite happy with that either, but we have voting for that.

Comment: I think describing this is as "really fun" and "cool" is quite misleading

Comment: You should not post it. The author of the game get inspiration from some discussions on Math.SE and when the game is finally ready. He has notified us by updating the question that kick start all this.

Comment: You could add a link to your profile page.

Comment: Not everything should be posted in every possible place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where do I post this?

Facebook, Google+, Reddit, Twitter, ...

The list goes on. You are also free to bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). But my personal opinion is that it doesn't belong on the [main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Besides, [the game has already been mentioned on the main page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373672/about-euclids-elements-and-modern-video-games) in the context of a different question...

Comment: A few other occurrences of this particular game can be found on main and in chat: [euclidthegame site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=euclidthegame+site:stackexchange.com). At the moment the first hit in that search is this: [Euclid the Game Level 2: Construct a line that bisects the given angle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839963/euclid-the-game-level-2-construct-a-line-that-bisects-the-given-angle). It is a question about this game, but obviously it is not posted solely for the purpose of promoting the website; so it is a perfectly valid question for this site.